# けど in the end of sentence

Tags: grammar

> 無理をしないように言ったけど。。

Is it an incomplete sentence? So she want to say "although I have told him not to overdo things... (he did it anyway).

Here's the full story for the context...

> 今日、鈴木くんに会った時、手があかくなっていておどろいた。木からおりられなくなった 子猫をたすけにいって 子猫にかまれたらしい。 鈴木くんは、子猫がけがをしなくてよかったと言っていたけど、鈴木くんは優しすぎるから、とても心配だ。無理をしないように言ったけど。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## English

It is a common idiom to leave the second half B of "A but B" phrases empty, leaving the meaning implicit.  This works in English in some cases as well, but is extremely common with most Japanese versions of "but".

In this case, it reads like "(I) said not to overdo it, but ...", or tweaked a little:

> "Even if (I) say not to overdo it, ...".

Here, the implication is that the speaker believes in the wisdom of the advice to "not overdo it", but also sees **some not-explicitly-stated reasons (at least in that sentence) for why** 鈴木くん may still go against the advice.  (Side note, the "he is kind" from the previous sentence is almost certainly being alluded to in this case).

---

**Aside**: Japanese also often abbreviates the A part, resulting in sentences starting with だけど、ですが、etc.  In these cases, A becomes whatever is appropriate from prior context, likely including something from the prior sentence.  It is actually not uncommon to see just a lone 「ですが……」.  For example, one speaker states a long explanation.  There is a pause, then the other speaker says 「ですが……」, and then falls silent again.  This could mean something along the lines of "Well, I see what you're saying, but ...  (I can't completely agree with your conclusion)"

## 日本語

「AだがB」という表現のBを省略し、言外に含ませるのは、日本語では慣用的な言い方です。英語でもこういう使い方ができることがありますが、日本語の逆接ではきわめて一般的なことです。

この例の場合、「(I) said not to overdo it, but ...」、もしくは少し言い換えて、

> "Even if (I) say not to overdo it, ...".

とでも訳せるかと思います。

ここで言わんとしているのは、「話し手自身は『無理をしない』という忠告が最も賢明だと思うが、同時に鈴木くんがこの忠告に反するだろう​**（少なくともこの文では）明言されていないもっともな理由**も思い当たる」ということです（ちなみに、この場合は直前の文にある「鈴木くんは優しすぎる」というのがほとんど答えのようなものですが）。

---

**余談**: 日本語では、Aが省略されて「だけど」や「ですが」などで始まる文章も多くみられます。この場合、前の文脈（例えばすぐ前の文）にある適切な要素がAとして用いられます。さらに言えば、「ですが……」だけの文も珍しくありません。例えば、Aさんが長い説明を言い終わり、一瞬間を置いて、Bさんが「ですが……」と言って、また無言になる、という具合です。これは言うなれば「確かに言いたい事はわかりますが、……（でもその結論にはちょっと納得できない）」のような意味合いになります。