# Meaning of だけれど at sentence end

Tags: meaning, words

I'm finding difficult to understand how だけれど is used [here](https://kumacdn.club/wp-content/uploads/R/Runway%20de%20Waratte/Chapter%20119/013.jpg).

> 〝藤戸千雪〟
>
> あの子、技術と勘はかなりいいわよね
>
> …ただ
>
> 〝技術〟じゃ差が出ないのよ
>
> ショーモデルは〝歩き〟と〝ポーズ〟をちゃんと鍛えてくるから
>
> だからこそ〝身長〟と〝雰囲気（オーラ）〟の世界って言われるのだけれど

I think I understand what the text mean:

> Fujito Chiyuki.
>
> Her technique and intuition are quite good.
>
> But...
>
> Technique can't make a difference.
>
> Because models train well their walking and poses.
>
> That's why it's said it's a world of height and aura.

I can't understand what the final だけれど means, though, it seems like the sentence would have the same meaning also without it. I know it as meaning "though, much as", with doesn't really seem to fit and seems in contrast with だからこそ ("Technique doesn't make a difference, and that's exacly why height and aura are important, though"? Sounds quite odd to me).

As a context, she is very short, too short to be a runway model (158 cm), but has an impressive skill and gives out a powerful aura (like the impression on the audience), so while she is heavily handicapped due to her height, she trained to have everything else a model needs.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43279/45489

Comment: What does the next panel look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s very hard to explain why, but the sentence would sound a bit odd in this context, to me at least, if it didn’t end with some expression that corresponds to “however” or “though.”

> だからこそ〝身長〟と〝雰囲気（オーラ）〟の世界って言われるのだ。

The last line is not meant to be a matter-of-fact statement of new information like this. It is a known fact, at least for the speaker, that the world of modeling is one in which mere height and “aura” (exuding from elegant bearing) determine success. Her observation that technique alone doesn’t make a difference because models train themselves vying to excel in walking and posing is both a symptom and a cause of that reality. だからこそ expresses the sense that it is **precisely why** the world of modeling is what it is said to be. けれど at the end kind of brings the focus back to what the speaker said earlier, reflecting the circular relationship that makes it somewhat self-evident.

It’s very hard to explain.

Comment: Could you expand about "Her observation that technique alone doesn’t make a difference because models train themselves vying to excel in walking and posing is both a symptom and a cause of that reality"? I'm not sure I understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Mauro - In modeling, successful competitors train well in walking and posing (besides being tall). This is because they know height and aura are important. On the other hand, the more they do so, the more important height and aura become to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possibilities.

1. What's written on the next page? If this sentence continues to the next page, だけど is used to give an introductory information leading to the main part on the next page. See: [けど usage in ”魔石灯”がいい例だけど、”魔石”は…](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010)
2. If 1 is not the case, this だけど is simply "however...", and the remaining part is left unsaid. The omitted sentence can be something like "she doesn't understand this fact yet" (or whatever you think fits the context).

Comment: Next page doesn't continue that sentence: https://kumacdn.club/wp-content/uploads/R/Runway%20de%20Waratte/Chapter%20119/014.jpg.