# What does this means in this context ?古物収集が趣味で色々と集めてるとは思ってたけど。 (MC found an old bronze mirror inside his uncle's warehouse/ storage room)

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games

**When reading, there is a sentence which i'm not sure about its meaning, since I'm new at JP. Appreciates if someone can correct my understanding if it was wrong o/**

**古物収集が趣味で色々と集めてるとは思ってたけど。**
**(my guess : "I've been thinking that his hobby is collecting antiques, since he's been collecting a lots of them." ? but i'm not sure )**

Context: MC found an old bronze mirror inside his uncle's warehouse/ storage room. And this sentence is describing his thought about his uncle.

MC「これ、なんだろ？鏡？でもガラスもはまってないし……あ、銅鏡ってやつかな」

辛うじて顔が映ってるような……そんな具合に小汚い銅鏡を手にとってみる。​

MC「伯父さんも趣味人だねぇ。これ、いくらしたんだろ」

**古物収集が趣味で色々と集めてるとは思ってたけど。​**

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/xjov56/comment/ipc0p17/ .

Comment: This has the "video-games" tag. Does that mean the quote is from a game? What is the title? Mentioning the title could provide additional context, and it's generally nice to give credits when quoting an extended amount of text from a creative work.

Answer (score 2):

The けど is the same as

- [けど in the end of sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36037/45489)
- [What does this けど at the end of the sentence mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34195/45489)

Generally it is omitting something like *I'm not sure/I don't know*.

The sentence is 「(伯父さんは)古物収集が趣味でいろいろと集めてる」とは思ってたけど. So literally it means *I thought that his hobby is collecting antiques and he was collecting a variety of them, but..*. In this case, you can just consider there is omitting *I don't know*, or it connects to the preceding これいくらしたんだろ: *... he was collecting a lot of things, but I wonder how much all these cost*.

Comment: i hate JP when it's trying to be so mysterious =='

Comment: @casualreader Remember English article usage is just as cryptic to most learners :( .... Well for me of course it's worse.